# google sheet image function low resoluion problem

Tags: arrays, image, google-sheets, syntax, resolution

when i use google sheet image function,
then i found image's resoltion lower.

so i test 3 case.

case1 : image function use, hosting site 1(not google)
case2 : image function use, hosting site 2(not google)
case3 : google sheet image insert(insert -> image)

and i found only case3, there isn't low resoultion problem.

how can i do?

*here google sheet url that i tested
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IB9yMDXFrSZDUPbIGFy92BUWszd1Qzx2kdJEuLMpBe8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are `modes`

> mode – [ OPTIONAL – 1 by default ] – The sizing mode for the image
>
> 1 resizes the image to fit inside the cell, maintaining aspect ratio.
>
> 2 stretches or compresses the image to fit inside the cell, ignoring aspect ratio.
>
> 3 leaves the image at original size, which may cause cropping.
>
> 4 allows the specification of a custom size.

in your case, you should be using:

```
=IMAGE(B2, 3)
```

[image]

but keep in mind that the original size is 1266×420

[image]

so to get the original it would be:

```
=IMAGE(B2, 4, 420, 1266)
```

[image]

your C2 cell dimensions are 572×200 so for such a small cell it's best to use a smaller source. you can use https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

[image]

and some online resizing tool like https://picresize.com/

[image]

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHSyu.png

```
=IMAGE(B2, 4, 189, 570)
```

[image]

Comment: oh!!! thank you very much!!
so i understand when the google resize the image, resolution lower..? is that correct?

Comment: @kMin yes, that is right